# Error CORS Policy : La respuesta a la solicitud de verificación previa no pasa la verificación de control de acceso: no tiene el estado HTTP correcto

Tags: php, .htaccess

Buenas estoy desarrollando una app con Angular y PHP con autenticación con un token jwt, ya pude realizar mi Interceptor para agregarle el Bearer token, pero manda un error...!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando hago la misma solicitud por Postman si funciona!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Investigando más a fondo pude ver que el problema es que el navegador realiza una petición de OPTIONS antes de mandar el GET, y que esta solicitud OPTIONS no lleva el token por lo que no pasa por el control de verificación contenido en mi `.htaccess`
Y menciona que debo cambiar los requerimientos de autenticacion para que no verifique en las solicitudes de tipo OPTIONS
Y creo eso se cambia en el htaccess

Mi archivo de htaccess esta de esta forma:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on

SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*) index.php?controller=$1&action=$2
</IfModule>
```

Y entiendo que aquí es donde va la configuración sobre que métodos puede 'verificar', porque en mi api como tan mis headers estan asi

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-API-KEY, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization, Access-Control-Request-Method");
```

No sé si falta alguno o si aquí se pone, y mi clase la que debería abrir la solicitud, es decir : `http://localhost/api-prueba/user/index`

Y hace lo siguiente:

```
$auth = $_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'];
    if(isset($auth)){
        echo json_encode(array(
            "msg" => "exito",
            "token" => $auth
        ));
    }else{
        echo json_encode(array(
            "msg" => "failed"
        ));
    }
```

Que es básicamente para saber si funciona o no

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega esto al inicio del documento

```php
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, DELETE, PUT, PATCH, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: token, Content-Type');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1728000');
    header('Content-Length: 0');
    header('Content-Type: text/plain');
    die();
}
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

Basicamente antes de enviar la solicitud. se hace un `prefly` a `options`